# Network nic ordering from heat template

Tags: openstack

I have a vm with 3 network interfaces.

I create it through heat template.

I want the interfaces to be in a specific order in the vm (eth0 a_net, eth1 b_net, eth2 c_net).

How can I do the following?

I am using juno version

With the following configuration I have : eth0 a_net, eth2 b_net, eth1 c_net

```
vMyNode:
type: OS::Nova::Server
properties:
  flavor: m1.flavor
  image: vMyNode
  key_name: HPG9KeyPair
  name: Appliance
  networks:
    - port: {get_resource: a_net_port}
    - port: {get_resource: b_net_port}
    - port: {get_resource: c_net_port}
```

Comment: did u get colution for your requirement ? and if order of port given in "networks" section is same as what is presented to VM or do we need to match mac/PCI value ?
supposing all are sriov ports and a_net_port has vlan 100, b_net_port has vlan 101 and c_net_port has vlan 102 so should be sure of their PCI value order in VM without taking input from user ( as in I dont want user to give me UUID based on running openstack port list and greping appropriate)?